# Numbers $N$ where the reverse of $N$ is a multiple of $N$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to find numbers $N$ so that the reverse of $N$ is a multiple of $N$. $N$ and its reverse must not have leading $0$.

Excluding palindrome, the smallest $N$'s I've found are $1089$ and $2178$.

Are there any others?

Comment: It might be worth seeking cases in bases other than $10.$

Comment: [Reverse divisible number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_divisible_number)

Comment: Also see [A071685](https://oeis.org/A071685) and [A008919](https://oeis.org/A008919) in the OEIS.

Answer (score 2):

There is an infinite class of numbers, $22\cdot(10^n-1)=21999\dots78,$ for $n\geq 2,$ where there are $n-2$ $9$s.

Then the reverse is $87999\dots12=88\cdot (10^n-1).$

There is another infinite class of numbers $10891089…1089$ whose reverse is $98019801…9801=9×10891089…1089$.